# 2 is the oddest prime: équivalent français dans le même esprit?

Tags: expressions, anglais, mathématiques, jeux-de-mots

En anglais, un jeu de mot qui joue sur la double signification du mot *odd (étrange ou impair)* nous donne un succulent :

> 2 is the oddest prime number → 2 est le plus étrange/impair des nombres premiers

Comme 2 est le seul nombre premier pair, le déclarer plus impair que [l’infinité de tous les autres](https://blogdemaths.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/infinite-des-nombres-premiers-marre-deuclide/) est un peu surréaliste.

Il s’agit bien entendu d’une facétie, puisqu’il faut bien un *(et un seul)* premier nombre pair, si l’on veut pouvoir générer l’ensemble des autres. De la même façon, 3 ou 5 se trouvent eux aussi à la base de leur série de nombres divisibles par 3 ou 5, et constituent chacun un exemple unique parmi tous les nombres premiers de valeurs divisibles exactement par 3 ou 5.

Seulement, les restes d’une division par 2 séparent les nombres entiers en deux classes nommées et bien connues, les nombres pairs et les nombres impairs.

Les restes d’une division par 3 divisent les nombres entiers en trois classes, lesquelles ne possèdent pas une dénomination aussi familière. Cette absence de nom simple et reconnu, ainsi que le nombre grandissant de classes créées, rendent moins frappant le caractère unique des nombres suivants de la séquence des nombres premiers.

Et le flou ne fait qu’empirer avec les nombres premiers plus grands : il y aurait de plus en plus de classes de nombres à nommer, et il vient un point où le commun des mortels ne sait parfois même plus déterminer sans un grand effort si un nombre considéré est premier (combien de temps pour évaluer la primalité de 17081, de 17767, de 17987 ou de 17999, par exemple ?).

> 17081 est composé (19×29×31)
>  17767 est composé (109×163)
>  17987 est premier
>  17999 est composé (41×439)

Nonobstant toutes ses objections au bien-fondé du jeu de mot anglais, je demeure certain que le français possède les outils nécessaires pour créer un commentaire aussi mordant que l’original, et je suis intéressé de voir ce qui pourrait surgir de bien inspiré.

---

<sup>Comme il s’agit d’une demande pour laquelle il n’existe pas, à ma connaissance, de réponse toute faite, comme il s’agit de proposer sans certitude sur le devenir des propositions, j’ai voulu lancer le sujet sous étiquette wiki. Comme ce n’est [plus une option](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/721/13100), j’essaie comme question régulière, laissant à la modération le soin de décider si ça passera ou non.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En jouant sur le fait que "prime number" se traduit par "nombre premier", et que 1 n'est pas premier car il a un seul diviseur entier positif, on peut utiliser premier comme ordinal dans son sens premier, (ce qui fournit une paire paire de premiers impairs, mais là rien ne va plus):

```
Deux est le premier premier
```

Dans le même 'ordre' d'idée, on peut même affirmer que

```
Le troisième naturel est le premier premier
```

Si l'on aime jouer avec les mots, on peut aussi dire que:

> Deux est le pair des premiers

Ou encore

> Dieu le Père est premier

Pour terminer, un autre homonyme de pair (peer) permettrait de faire l'affirmation suivante (à éviter comme moyen mnémotechnique)

```
Dans le Royaume des naturels, tous les premiers sont pairs, sauf le premier qui est pair.
```

Comment: *Dans le Royaume des naturels, etc.* est fabuleux! Pas idéal comme moyen mnémotechnique, en effet, mais quel jeu sur les mots. Un grand merci de l’avoir partagé.

Answer (score 2):

Voici deux suggestions:

- Deux est unique
- Deux est le nombre premier le plus singulier

Jeu de mots sur *Dieu est unique* et contradiction entre la pluralité de deux et l'unicité de un.

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais simplement enlevé le slash. J'ai lu « le plus étrange impair » et ça m'a paru du plus bel effet. Le jeu de mot se faisant avec « impair » comme dans « commettre un impair ».

Comment: Merci. J'avais bien raison de penser qu'il y avait assez de cerveaux ici pour me surprendre. J'avais bien sûr, depuis le temps que j'y songe, pensé au nom impair. Je ne savais pas quel adjectif y joindre et demeurais coincé là. Et voilà que ma présentation vous fait penser au premier abord à l'étrange déjà présent dans l'original anglais, et qui m'avait complètement échappé.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that to a French mathematician (or to any French person for that matter),

> [**un nombre impairement
>   pair**](http://publimath.irem.univ-mrs.fr/glossaire/NO010.htm)

would not sound like someone is playing around with words (and logic) to confuse the less mathematically-inclined among us.
When I first encountered it, however, I found it to have a somewhat tongue-twisting/alliterative quality  and I was even tempted to  try to translate it literally as the mildly playful “an oddly even number.”

Although [“impairement”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impairement) as used as an adverb here apparently has no connection with the “strangely/unusually” English sense of “oddly” that you seek, perhaps the following concoctions could qualify as being somewhat amusing (and they might even be mathematically, if not linguistically, correct):

> De tous les nombres premiers, aucun n’est plus impairement pair que
>   [le] 2.
>
> De tous les nombres premiers, seulement [le] 2 est impairement pair.
>   (This last one even kind of rhymes [at least to my anglo ears])

Answer (score 0):

Puisque Stéphane Gimenez est déjà tombé sur la structure que j’avais en tête ([sa réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31956/13100)), j’y vais de ce à quoi m’avaient mené mes réflexions :

> 2 est le plus gros impair des nombres premiers.

Là où la réponse de Stéphane collait remarquablement bien à l’étrangeté de l’original anglais, j’avais trouvé que **gros** surenchérissait sur le paradoxe du nombre 2 présenté comme un impair, celuis-ci étant d’entre tous les nombres premiers le plus petit.

J’avais aussi pensé à une tournure peut-être plus élégante, si pas aussi superlative :

> 2 est un gros impair dans les nombres premiers.

Comment: Non, ça va, un coup de sang ça se comprend. Laissons la vie passée comme elle est!

Answer (score -1):

Succulent? Oui! Mais jusqu'à un certain point seulement et puis cela s'arrête net à l'original anglais. Cette impitoyable réalité familière au traducteur,  la ponction d'effets substantiels qui accompagne immanquablement le passage d'une langue à l'autre, une fois de plus nous pliera à ses caprices, nous réduira à une courageuse note de bas de page dans laquelle nous ne pourront au plus qu'insinuer un faible espoir que le lecteur ait pu faire sienne la félicité d'une initiation aux arcanes de la langue d'origine.

Il est vrai qu'il arrive parfois que le génie indifférent de l'expression figurée qui guette le traducteur à chaque phrase ne soit pas à ses  rendez-vous désolants et qu'une vraiment heureuse transposition existe, le plus souvent cependant pas sans un changement de contexte.

Dans la traduction qui nous occupe la première possibilité (oddest → le plus étrange) n'implique pas de transposition de contexte, elle est factuelle et sera la seule possibilité à moins d'un miracle dans lequel je ne crois pas. Une note en bas de page par un traducteur soucieux de faire part au lecteur de l'esprit du texte original sera le seul recours dans le sens de réparer la perte. Il reste à voir pourquoi.

Considérons tout d'abord la seconde possibilité : oddest→le plus impair. Si on doit lire une expression de cette sorte dans le courant d'une phrase on ne peut pas manquer d'être arrêté : « impair » n'est pas un adjectif passible d'un sens superlatif, on ne comprend pas, ce n'est pas du français; il y a le recours des guillemets, bien sûr, mais cette solution dans ce cas particulièrement obscur ne va pas sans une explication qui doit suivre et dans ce cas aussi une explication ne convient pas; c'est assez obscur, n'oublions pas que l'on s'éloigne beaucoup de l'idée de parité. La langue doit rester la langue correcte, ceci est un principe des plus élémentaires avec lequel on ne transige pas. Bien sûr on pourra nous dire « Oui mais l'anglais « oddest » ne fait pas non plus partie de la langue anglaise en tant que superlatif de l'adjectif « odd ».». Cela n'est pas moins vrai, cependant cette acception du mot dans la phrase anglaise n'est pas celle qui s'impose naturellement, c'est l'acception du mot en tant que signifiant « étrange » qui est naturellement décodée à la lecture et cela parce que c'est la seule possible. La phrase anglaise est fondée sur cette acception et rien d'autre n'y transparait du point de vue sémantique; le fait entièrement accessoire de l'existence *hors de la phrase* d'une suggestion non négligeable mais non légitimée et que d'ailleurs on peut considérer avec des degrés variés d'amusement, et même comme une simple curiosité pas trop facile à éviter et sur laquelle l'auteur n'aurait pas nécessairement  misé<sup>1</sup>, n'entre pas dans le contenu informatif. Dans le français elle s'impose naturellement (et faussement) parce qu'elle est dans une construction superlative.

Considérons maintenant une autre possibilité. On a tout loisir, donné cette liberté que l'on se permet de prendre avec le langage selon la seconde possibilité, de passer à l'échelon supérieur, c'est à dire  de l'idée de  faire de l'adjectif « impair » un adjectif ayant un superlatif, se fixer sur celle d'en faire le nom « impair » qui signifie « maladresse, manque de tact pouvant avoir de fâcheuses conséquences » et dans cet usage de placer le mot déplacé entre guillemets; il n'y a rien de plus tiré par les cheveux, à mon avis, que cette association de concepts numériques avec des maladresses, des manques de tact et des conséquences fâcheuses;  je ne vois aucune porte de sortie dans cette possibilité, à laquelle néanmoins il n'est pas inutile de donner une chance; c'est une chance, malheureusement, qui me semble très rapidement réduite à rien, qui dévoile un état de choses forcé. C'est irrécupérable. Dit en passant, je ne vois pas ce qu'il y aurait de « mordant » dans ce jeux de mots, qui n'en est pas un vrai, qui est un jeux de mots  sans légitimité d'auteur, je ne vois pas ce qu'il y aurait de qualifiable comme « critiquant avec vivacité ». L'assertion, tous comptes faits, ne vise qu'à souligner l'individualité remarquable du nombre en tant que nombre premier.

<sub>1 Dans un ouvrage sérieux, un auteur anglais ou américain pourra dans un tel cas d'utilisation de mots ajouter une parenthèse telle que « (I beg your pardon for the understated pun) »</sub>

Comment: @Montée La vie est courte et l'art est long!

Comment: @Montée Why don't yo say something half sensical and keep to the subject? I don't mind opinions and clear cut arguments; do you mean I should have said "L'art est long et la vie est courte!"? I know, I made a little mistake.

Comment: Il est clair que vous vous inscrivez contre le point de départ de la question. Vous en aviez le droit, et vous auriez pu être dans le vrai. Les réponses fort ingénieuses soumises par des gens de meilleure volonté que vous ont réduit à néant votre tentative de nullifier la question. Too bad! Votre échec ne fait que mettre davantage en évidence votre partialité et votre nombrilisme. Un beau moins un pour votre effort.